# POSTMAN and Wordpress JWT: Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I installed JWT according to the instruction and tested the /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token restpoint via POSTMAN. But I get this response here:

Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Any hint?

BTW: /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate works!

Maybe something was messed up when i implemented an internal call to that restpoint? Here is how I do this call:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( ‘POST’, ‘/jwt-auth/v1/token’ );
$request->set_header(“Content-Type”,”application/json”);
$request->set_body(‘{“username”: “‘.$username.'”,   “password”: “‘.$password.'”}’);
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data( $response, false );
$response = $data;
```

This call works by the way! It is just not reachable from the outside.

EDIT: It seems it has to do with a custom filter. When I deactivate the filter, the restpoint works again. Check here the extension iwth the commented out filter:

```
function extend_token( $data, $user ) {

  $isProvider = get_user_meta($user->ID, "isProvider", true); 

  if($isProvider == true)
  {
    $data['isProvider'] = 'true';
    $profileData = get_profile_data_by_userId($user->ID);
    $data = array_merge($data, $profileData); 
    $unitData = get_unit_data_by_userId($user->ID);
    $data = array_merge($data, $unitData); 
    $offerData = get_offer_data_by_userId($user->ID);
    $data = array_merge($data, $offerData);     
    $eventData = get_event_data_by_userId($user->ID);
    $data = array_merge($data, $eventData);         
  }  
    return $data;  
}
//add_filter( 'jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', 'extend_token', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the extend_token function called other sub functions which contained database connections with invalid parameters. So I jsut fixed the connection and it works again.